# Changing interface method arguments

Tags: java

Let's say I have interface MyInterface that has method `do()`. I have some classes that implement this interface. This interface is called throughout the code and calls specific implementation via Factory. Later on I decide to change `do()` method by adding an argument to it, let's say - `do(numberOfTimes)`. Now all clients are broken so that when I call `MyInterfaceOld.do()` implementation `do()` method will not be found. I can add another `do()` method with extra argument, but this breaks clients as well. The straightforward way is to change `do()` method in MyInterface and update all clients, but is there another way without needing to update all clients?

Comment: Java 8's `default` methods.

Comment: In general, interfaces can't evolve. Default methods address some of the pain though, allowing addition of new methods.

Comment: biziclop, I understand. But this is a welcomed change I am sure.